The (n-1)-dimensional sphere of the product of a unital ring
Given a ring $R$ with identity define the $(n−1)$-dimensional sphere $S^{n−1}(R)$ to be the set of all elements of $R^n$ that have at least one invertible component.
I want to ask:

Why is the sphere defined like this?
Why the dimension of this set is $n-1$?

I read some references and found that one can directly define similar balls and spheres of a discrete valuation field:
Let $K$ be a complete discrete valuation field with valuation $\text{val}$, and $R$ be the ring of integers(consisting of the elements $x$ such that $\text{val}(x)\ge 0$).
Let $B^d(K)$ (resp. $S^{d−1}(K))$ denote the unit ball (resp. the unit sphere) in $K^d$. Clearly, $B^d(K) = R^d$ and $S^{d−1}(K)$ consists of tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_d) \in R^d$ containing at least one coordinate which is invertible in $R$.
I can understand why $B^d(K)= R^d$ but still I don't know why the element in $S^{d−1}(K))$ has at least one invertible coordinate.
Thank you.
